# Am having difficult to compile C file with vsCode

Tags: c

Am using VsCode to compile c file after applying the mingw64 but am having the following error

```
c://mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ming32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find _putchar: no such file or directory collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 _putchar.c 100-main.c 100-print_times_table.c -o 100-times_table
```

And expected

100-print_times_table.exe

Comment: That is an...interesting naming convention.
That said, the one reporting the error is not the compiler, it's the linker. And it's telling you that it cannot find the function body of '_putchar'.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium For me, the strange thing is that it complains about "no such file or directory". Not about an "unresolved reference".

Comment: What happens if you use `gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 _putchar.c` ? And  with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 100-main.c` and with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89 100-print_times_table.c` ?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium It seems it cannot find a *file* named `_putchar`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The error doesn't seem to result from the command shown.

Answer (score 0):

There's may be an easy way to solve this problem. You can downgrade "C/C++" to this version--v1.8.4. Then vsCode will generate configuration files automatically. Then you can compile C file with it easily. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your with to help is appreciated. Nevertheless, without knowing what is wrong with the compilation command, it is hard to see how this would help to solve it.